# Subtract two Values in for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to subtract two values `MaxTaxFreeValue` - `Reduction` inside a for-each loop but I get `NaN` as a result. How do I fix this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Position">
    <TR CLASS="position leftRightPadding">
        <TD />
        <TD CLASS="alignRight" STYLE="min-width:85px;"><xsl:value-of select="Date" /></TD>
        <TD CLASS="alignLeft"><xsl:value-of select="Text" /></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue"/></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="Reduction"/></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select=number("MaxTaxFreeValue" - "Reduction")/></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="Account"/></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="ValueAddedTaxPercentValue"/></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="KindOfPayment"/></TD>
        <xsl:for-each select="FreeFields/FreeField">
            <TD class="alignLeft"><xsl:value-of select="Value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></TD>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </TR>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Are you sure you get `NaN` and not a syntax error (due to the value of the `select` attribute not being delimited by quotation marks)? The expression should actually be `<xsl:value-of select="number(MaxTaxFreeValue) - number(Reduction)"/>`

Comment: Tried your suggestion `<xsl:value-of select="number(MaxTaxFreeValue) - number(Reduction)"/>` and I'm still getting NaN as a result

Comment: Can you show your input XML, as that suggests one (or both) of `MaxTaxFreeValue` or `Reduction` are not actually numeric. Thanks!

Comment: I think in `<xsl:value-of select=number("MaxTaxFreeValue" - "Reduction")/>` why you use `"` char it is converting as string that may be posibilities to get `NaN` need to do like `<xsl:value-of select=number(MaxTaxFreeValue) - number(Reduction)/>` it is better to show both tags with values in XML.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have access to the input xml itself because I'm editing inside layout editor. E.g. `MaxTaxFreeValue` has a value of `24` and `Reduction` has a value of `4`. Trying `<xsl:value-of select=number(MaxTaxFreeValue) - number(Reduction)/>` returns `false`.

Comment: If you do `<xsl:value-of select="MaxTreeValue" /> - <xsl:value-of select="Reduction" />` what do you see?

Comment: Then it displays both values without actually subtracting them

Comment: Yes. But I just wanted to confirm it literally showed "24 - 4" to ensure the elements did actually contain the values you expected..... Thanks!

Comment: It literally contains `24,00 € - -14,40` which is equal to both values.

Comment: Please show your input. You **can** get it using an *identity transform*. Note that neither `24,00 €` nor `-14,40` are numbers in XML/XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT/XPATH numbers must use a full-stop as the decimal indicator, not a comma as is used in some cultures. It can also not contain any currency symbols (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#NT-Number)

So, you will need to remove any currency symbol or space from your element, and then convert to the number. If your values is limited to what it contains, you can do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(translate(MaxTaxFreeValue, ',€ ', '.')) 
                        + number(translate(Reduction, ',€ ', '.'))" />
```

Note the use of `+` here, not `-`. If you subtract a negative number from another number, then this is the same as adding the positive version of that number, so I think you actually need addition here if `Reduction` is always going to be negative.

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAN as an example. Note that this only works with the Euro currency symbol, and also assumes the elements are non-empty.

On the other hand, if you want to handle any unexpected symbols, or if the elements may be empty, you probably need to create a named template to do the conversion, as you would need to do more work with a double-translate:

```
<xsl:template name="convertToNumber">
  <xsl:param name="element" />
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="normalize-space($element)">
          <xsl:value-of select="translate($element, concat(',', translate($element, '-01234567890', '')), '.')" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The nested translate will return the non-numeric characters in the string, which is then used to remove them from the main string.

Then, you can make use of variables, which call this template, to do the calculation

```
<xsl:variable name="maxTaxFreeValue">
    <xsl:call-template name="convertToNumber">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="MaxTaxFreeValue" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="reduction">
    <xsl:call-template name="convertToNumber">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="Reduction" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="number($maxTaxFreeValue) + number($reduction)" />
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAN/1 for an example of this

Of course, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use a function instead of a named template, along with the `replace` statement.

```
<xsl:function name="my:convertToNumber" as="xs:decimal">
  <xsl:param name="element" />
  <xsl:value-of select="if (normalize-space($element)) then replace(replace($element, ',', '.'), '[^\.\-0-9]', '') else 0" />
</xsl:function>
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAN/2 for an example of this.

Comment: Got access to the XML now. My XML looks like this `<MaxTaxFreeValue><![CDATA[24,00 �]]></MaxTaxFreeValue>`

Comment: Using `<xsl:value-of select="number(translate(MaxTaxFreeValue, ',€ ', '.')) 
                        - number(translate(Reduction, ',€ ', '.'))" />` returns `NaN` and using `<xsl:value-of select="number(translate(MaxTaxFreeValue, concat(',', translate(MaxTaxFreeValue, '-01234567890', '')), '.')) 
                       - number(translate(Reduction, concat(',', translate(Reduction, '-01234567890', '')), '.'))" />` returns NaN if either `MaxTaxFreeValue` or `Reduction` is empty. It also adds the minus values instead of subtracting them. E.g. 24 - -14,40 is 38.4

Comment: If you subtract a negative number, then this would be expected. 24 minus -14. does indeed equal 38.4. Is the reduction always going to be negative?

Comment: Yes it's always negative. Also it's possible that Reduction or either MaxTaxFreeValue has no value at all, then it returns NaN

Comment: I revised my answer to handle this.

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much. If i might add, how do I add the € character after `<xsl:value-of select="number($maxTaxFreeValue) + number($reduction)"/>` so it doesn't just show the number.

Comment: Just add `<xsl:text>€</xsl:text>` after the `xsl:value-of` statement.

Comment: Just saw that it cut's off the 0's after the , if `MaxTaxFreeValue` is `12,00 €` and `Reduction` is `emtpy` it shows only 12 €. How do I change it so it doesn't cut off the 0s?

Comment: You should read up on `format-number` to handle this (which you will probably need to use in conjunction with `xsl:decimal-format` if you want to display with a comma too). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576454/format-numbers-in-xml-using-xslt for example.

Comment: I edited it to `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number($maxTaxFreeValue), '###,###.00', 'en') + format-number(number($reduction), '###,###.00', 'en')"/>`. However it doesn't change anything. I added `<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />
    <xsl:decimal-format name="en" decimal-separator='.' grouping-separator=',' />` to the top of the file

Comment: You should put `format-number` around the whole expression, not the individual parts of the expression. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAN/3